# Linq statement to return number of rows

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, razor

I am passing assesment model to the Results Action using redirect to action. In the Results action controller I would like to 
to execute a linq statement to retrieve the number of rows using the repository and whatever values are posted.for example

```
number of rows = Select * 
                 from table or model
                 where SmokesInHouse = SmokesInHouse And
                       SmokesInCar = SmokesInCar And
                       SmokesAtWork = SmokesAtWork'
```

```
public class SampleController : Controller
{
    private IEnvRepository repository;

    public SampleController(IEnvRepository assesmentRepository)
    {
        repository = assesmentRepository;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SmokingEnvironments(Assessment a)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)

            return RedirectToAction("Results", new { SmokesInHouse =SmokesInHouse,        SmokesInCar  = a.SmokesInCar, SmokesAtWork=a.SmokesAtWork });
        }
        return View(a);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Results()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to update the `Results` action to accept the `Assessment` model i.e.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Results(AssessmentModel assessment)
{
    int rows = myTable.Where(x => x.SmokesInHouse == assessment.SmokesInHouse &&
                                  x.SmokesInCar == assessment.SmokesInCar &&
                                  x.SmokesAtWork == assessment.SmokesInWork).Count();
    return View(rows);
}
```

Comment: `X.Where(P).Count()` is equivalent to `X.Count(P)`.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following to get the total number of smokers in your model:

```
int totalSmokers = model.Where(x => x.SmokesInHouse && x.SmokesInCar && x.SmokesAtWork).Count();
```

You would use the same where clause if querying from a database table.

Comment: The OP says the condition is `AND` not `OR`.

Answer (score 0):

There's an overload of the [Count method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb534807.aspx) that takes a predicate. With it the query can be simplified to something like:

```
int totalSmokers = xs.Count(x =>
    x.SmokesInHouse == a.SmokesInHouse &&
    x.SmokesInCar == a.SmokesInCar &&
    x.SmokesAtWork == a.SmokesAtWork);
```

I'm assuming this is an IQueryable that will be executed on the server and it might not make difference. But if it was an IEnumerable it could make a difference for large sequences.